# WordPress ACF: add default rows to Repeater field type in admin section for a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The Advanced Custom Fields plugin for WordPress provides a Repeater type field. I already know how to add rows to this via the code but what I don't know is how to get the wp-admin console for the custom post to include this code so that the dynamically added rows are shown in the editor.

So that's the question: where do I put my custom `add_rows()` function if I want those rows to be visible to the editor?

Currently I have the `add_rows()` code in the single page template for that custom post type.. which of course doesn't render to the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is twofold:

1. Firstly there's no need to `add_rows()` (which modifies the DB) for the admin section . I just used a filter instead which modifies the values directly, as described in this article here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/dynamically-generate-subfield-content/
2. To make it run in the admin console, the code should be in functions.php rather than in the custom post type template.